# Eigenfaces Algorithm

Tags: eigenvalues, machine-learning, data-analysis

This might be a silly quesntion but recently I've been trying to program the eigenface algorithm using PCA, so I arranged the face vectors vertically in a matrix X such as: X = [x1,x2,x3,...,xn]; 
In this case, what would be the wright way of computing the covariance matrix? cov(X) or cov(X')?

Comment: Depends on how the covariance function is implemented in your specific programming environment, but with data along the columns you should have $\Sigma = \frac{1}{n-1}(X-\mu\mathbf{1}^T)(X-\mu\mathbf{1}^T)^T$ if you want to do it yourself

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but one thing I have trouble understanding is why isn't the covariance in this case the inner product of X with itself, is there any intuitive explanation?

Comment: Note that to compute the basis you should *not* form the covariance matrix, but instead compute the SVD of X (with or without removing its average first, it doesn’t matter much in practice). Then the columns of U are your basis. Computing the product X^T X directly is bound to introduce round-off errors, which tend to corrupt the basis vectors, especially the ones associated with the smaller singular values.

Comment: Do you have any sugestion of books I could read on the issue?

Comment: Which issue are you referring to?

Comment: Just compute the SVD of $X$ such that $X = U \Sigma V^T$ and then choose the columns of $U$ with the $k$ largest singular values in $\Sigma$, where $k$ is up to you. These columns correspond to the eigenvectors (aka eigenfaces in your context) with the largest $k$ eigenvalues of the covariance matrix for $X$, so it is exactly what you want but much better conditioned and probably faster to compute.

Comment: @Marcus To explain why it is an outer product, recall that the covariance matrix is an estimate of the covariances of the components of the random vector $\mathbf{X} = (X_1,X_2,\dots,X_m)$. If we consider each face vector to be a realization of this random vector, then the covariances can be estimated like $\mathrm{cov}(X_i,X_j) = E[(X_i-\mu_i)(X_j-\mu_j)]\approx \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n((x_k)_i-\mu_i)((x_k)_j-\mu_j)$, but this is just $\Sigma_{ij}$, the $ij$-th entry of the covariance matrix. Turns out that vectorizing the equations for the covariance estimates just needs an outer product

Comment: Also for a more heuristic argument, if we had a matrix of inner products, the resulting matrix would be size $n\times n$, but $n$ has nothing to do with the underlying random process, it is just the number of realizations we have access too. Any covariance matrix would have to be size $m\times m$ where $m$ is the dimension of each data point $x_i$.

Comment: @spektr since the OP is interested in PCA, it is important that the data is shifted to mean 0 prior to the SVD computation to ensure that the interpretation of the singular values and vectors are correct. The difference between the linear subspace from the SVD and affine subspace from the PCA can be quite different when you need to interpret your data instead of just fitting it

Comment: @whpowell96 yes, I agree. I was lazy and treating $X$ as zero meaned data without explicitly saying so, so whoops. Should have defined a different thing, say $\bar{X}$ as the zero mean version of the data.

Comment: Here is a great book which also gives matlab codes http://www.databookuw.com/